# Dart: How to implement a similar situation like "when hashcode() is overridden, ==() should also be overridden"?

Tags: dart, language-features

When either hashCode() or == operator is overridden in a class, the dart analyzer warns, saying that the other method should also be overridden.

Can I implement a similar case on other methods? Or is this feature a special case provided by Dart Analyzer?

For exmaple,

```
class A {
  void method1() {}

  void method2() {}
}

class B extends A {
  @override
  void method1() {}
}
```

At this point I want to produce a warning that class B should also override method2(). Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is a linter rule. The dart analyzer implements a bunch of these which you can view [here](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/) or check out just [that specific rule](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/hash_and_equals.html). 
While you can [customize static analysis](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options) for your project, as far as I can tell support for custom linting rules is still [not available](https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues/697) (yet).