# Extend Dart analyzer features

Tags: dart, dart-analyzer

I'm currently building a framework on Dart and would like to throw static errors and warnings for the user on the 'Problems' tab on VS Code.

If not possible, throw warnings based on annotations would be very helpful, like the meta package.

I more or so understand the dart analyzer package but I can't see how could I integrate it (if possible at all) with the dart-code extension for VS Code.

Will I have to implement a whole extension for VS Code?

Comment: It's not currently possible to extend the `dart-analysis` tool, so you'd have to write your own separate plugin with language analysis to show custom static warnings/errors in the Problems window.

Comment: My recent answer on another question has some relevant information you may find useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64255267/64269813#64269813

Comment: Thanks for the replies. It would be really great to have some kind of custom static analysis in the dart core process. For now, i'll stick to just check at runtime and build an extension later.